# Different background color on each categories

Tags: php, html, css, categories, taxonomy

How can I display my categories in different background color using a custom post?
I like to echo the slug name from my taxonomy to become the class attributes of span and style it in css. but I can't able to echo the slug name and I can't display the category name at the same time.

```
    <?php $post_terms = get_the_terms(); ?>
        <span class="<?php echo $post_terms[0]->slug; ?>">
            Categories: <?php echo $post_terms[0]->cat_name; ?>
        </span>
```

can you show me what is the right code?

Comment: Why can you not output both at the same time? What does that actually mean, "can't" - what result are you actually getting with this attempt then?

Comment: hi @CBroe I need to display the category name and echo the slug name at the same time to become the class attribute of span so I can style the different background color in the css. I can do this in get_the_categories(), but in get_the_terms() it don't work. I am looking for the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that using this codes;

```
    <?php $category = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'your_taxonomy_cat_name' ); ?> 
        <span class="post-category-color-text <?php echo $category[0]->slug; ?>">
        Categories: <?php  foreach ( $category as $cat){ echo $cat->name;}?>
    </span>
```

I hope this code will help you. happy coding

Comment: hi @Marvin Acosta thank you for this code, you are great programmer you understand the problem and scenario. this will be 100% help. cheers!